# mocha browser globals, where are they?

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, mocha.js, global

This is for browser mocha:

I am wondering how I can access the globals defined in mocha.globals like this:

```
var myVar = {var: 'var'};

mocha.globals(['myVar']);
```

How can I access myVar in my test?

It's in neither of these contexts:

- window.myVar
- mocha.myVar
- mocha.options.myVar
- mocha.options.globals.myVar

How am I supposed to access the mocha globals in browser mocha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I access `myVar` in my test?

If you made `myVar` a global, which does not seem to be the case in the code you show, you access it like any other JavaScript global.

You seem to be thinking that you can use a scoped variable, pass it to `mocha.globals()`, and then it will become a global variable. But that's not what `mocha.globals()` is for. You use this method to tell Mocha to ignore some globals that may leaked during testing. If you turn on Mocha's leak checking, it will report variables leaked into the global space. But sometimes, you are testing software that *wants* to leak *some* variables in the global space. You use `mocha.globals()` give to Mocha the names of the globals it should not warn about.

Comment: _You seem to be thinking that you can use a scoped variable, pass it to mocha.globals(), and then it will become a global variable._

Yes, exactly, I thought it was for turning local variables into global ones. Thanks for correcting my misconception. Finally, it makes sense. Awesome!